# neo4j - how do I model node schema less?

Tags: database, database-design, neo4j

I read some where that noe4j or other nosql database is schemaless. so what is the schemaless? I would like to know more about it with use case.

Comment: You won't create tables, no data definition/no types, you only push key=value into the db, only data manipulation.

Comment: I've  been looking for a solution/pattern to create a schemaless node for my neo4j ecommerce site. Clearly creating schemaless nodes in Neo4J is not a problem. My big problem is tro create a model, in my case c# model (same applies to Java). Since models are pre-defined, how can a model handle a schemaless node? Please let me knoe if you've got some ideas.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to define a schema like you would have to do e.g. in mysq with a table. Instead, you can add properties and their value to each individual node (entry), as you like.

E.g: if you look at the address book in an android phone a person entry can have a multitude of properties - phone numbers, addresses, names. Some people have a lot of attributes, some have none.

Doing something like that with a schema (e.g. table structure) is really hard, and requires advance planning of what your fields are, and how you want to query them in the future.

Without a schema you can more or less play it by ear, and add things as needed.

What needs deciding though is what to add as property to a node, and what as a related node. E.g. is an address a node, or just a property of a person? (Most likely a seperate node, but it depends on your use case)

Comment: Thanks @JoergBaach. So, How can we retrieve it. means I want to say, some object has 2 properties, and other objects has 5 properties. and If I have to give some tabular report, how can I do this?

Comment: You can for instance return null in case a property does not exist (use `?`), and use Cypher for tabular output, see http://console.neo4j.org/r/yinfyw