# Are there any Graph Databases that allow you to define the labels and relationships (schema) first

Tags: database, neo4j, graph-databases, orientdb, titan

I am looking to build a graph database for a new site that I'm building and came across neo4j.

Although it is a viable option, I don't like the idea of creating the labels and relationships on the fly. Instead I only want to define the labels and relationships before hand so my database can have a bit more stability to it.

Pretty much like a RDBMS where we define the tables and properties first but instead I want to define the labels and relationships and their properties first.

Comment: What is the benefit ? oO  RDBMS are not schema-less. Neo4j is and it's one of its strongest point.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17881003/985949

Comment: I guess developing and maintaining at the database level, it will prevent me or other developers from adding new labels by mistake. eg a developer might mistype a label when adding a node to the db. They might add a node of Label "Persons" when there has already been n amount of nodes with the Label "Person" in the database. This way if a developer tried to add a node of type "Persons" by mistake, an error would be displayed saying "that label has not yet been defined"

Comment: Personally, I use Spring-Data-Neo4j to let the set of labels automatic. You can't do what you expect upfront with a schema-less database. If the developer is able to make a mistake in labels...I can't imagine what type of mistakes he could do regarding values.. Developer should be "professional", and scarce mistakes can happen in every aspect, not just  db-schemas. You can't avoid it.

Comment: An important benefit to having the option to define a schema lies in the underlying graph database's ability to optimize queries based on the knowledge of the schema itself.  This optimization can lead to considerable performance gains.

Answer (score 2):

[OrientDB](http://orientdb.com) allows you to do that. Look at:

- http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Tutorial-Using-schema-with-graphs.html
- http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Graph-Schema.html

Comment: Yes this is what I am looking for. Does OrientDb work well with c#?. I've noticed there are some nuget solutions for this but cannot find any other documentation on it.

Answer (score 2):

[Titan](http://titandb.io) allows you do that also.

- http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/0.9.0-M2/schema.html

Of particular interest to the original post, in section 5.5: It is strongly encouraged to explicitly define all schema elements and to disable automatic schema creation by setting `schema.default=none` in the Titan graph configuration.

Comment: Yes this is what I am looking for. Does Titan work well with c#?. I've noticed there are some nuget solutions for this but cannot find any other documentation on it.

Comment: For Titan, you'd need to leverage the Titan Server for non-JVM environments. http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/0.9.0-M2/server.html The server uses either WebSockets or REST. It is based on [Apache TinkerPop3](http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org).

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is define this befor me the devoloper entered this in graph format (like a template?) for example, what is the node, it's properties, the relation...etc